# How to delete a file even if it is locked in windows 7?

Tags: file-io, windows-7, window

I need to delete a file programmatically even if the file is locked. I get a locked state and I can't figure out, which process it locks. It is no system file, but my own created file. It is still locked, after closing all my applications.

How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693076/how-to-force-delete-a-file

Answer (score 1):

If the "Process Explorer method" didn't help, try:

1. remember the path, kill "Windows Explorer", delete in CMD console, and restart Explorer
2. Use ForceDel (https://github.com/michaelknigge/forcedel)
3. Use UnlockIt (http://emcosoftware.com/unlock-it)

If none of them works, you'll probabely not be able to delete the file/folder. You can then use LockHunter (http://lockhunter.com/) to automatically delete it after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "process explorer" to find the process that locks it.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Open process explorer click the binocular icon and search the file name.